# Why is the time.Add method not working on this time.Time variable with format time.RFC3339 to increment the day?

Tags: go, time

This code makes a time in Format time.RFC3339 changes the hour to 00:00 when 24 is found and then should increment the day, however this is not happening. Please share thoughts :)

```
package main
    
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

var dConv time.Time //contains converted time
var timeErr error

func main() {
    dateTime := "2020-01-01" + "T" + "24:00" + ":00Z"
    if strings.Contains(dateTime, "T24") {
        dateTime = strings.Replace(dateTime, "T24", "T00", 1)
        dConv, timeErr = time.Parse(time.RFC3339, dateTime)
        h := dConv
        if timeErr == nil {
            fmt.Println(h)
            h.AddDate(0, 0, 1)
            fmt.Println(h)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not saving the return value. Please [read the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.AddDate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`time.Add()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Add) method does not modify the receiver time, it can't as it's not a pointer receiver. Instead it returns the result `time.Time` which you don't assign to anything so it's discarded.

If you assign it back to `h`, you'll see the result incremented by a day:

```
h = h.AddDate(0, 0, 1)
```

With this change output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UVvia0ZXUOg)):

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2020-01-02 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```